# Abysmal update performance with a very simple query in Blazegraph 2.1.4

Tags: sparql, blazegraph

The following update query takes 1.7 seconds in Blazegraph:

```
DELETE {<http://my.site/Statement> :count ?existingObject}
INSERT {<http://my.site/Statement> :count "19" . } 
WHERE {<http://my.site/Statement> :count? ?existingObject}
```

The query is part of a transaction, called using Sesame's `prepareUpdate`, where `setAutoCommit` has been set to `false` (time does not include commit time, performed later).

I have an SSD drive with an i7 processor.

Does anybody have a solution or alternative approach?

Comment: If the `INSERT` works now, it would be good to mention that in the other thread and maybe also provide the solution. This avoids others from spending time on issues that are already solved.

Comment: The INSERT DATA doesn't crash any longer, thanks for your useful help on that, and I've mentioned that in the other thread. However, it has the same kind of abysmal performance as this

Comment: Did you mean to put in `:count?` which is a property path.

Comment: Yes the property path is deliberate. It is basically to replace any existing value or create a new one if it doesn't exist